# Add force for jumping but also move the character on the x axis

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm adding force to the rigidbody2D for jumping :

```
rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpForce));
```

The rigidbody jumps on the Y axis but how I can smoothly move the caracter on the X axis when jumping?

Consider the following example : I should jump from a platform to another because the game is infinite runner.

Answer (score 0):

Add a horizontal force.

> rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(horizontalForce, verticalForce));

Answer (score 0):

you can move it by setting the position of it 
transform.position=new vector3(transform.position.x+speed*Time.deltatime,transform.position.y,transform.position.z);

and when jumping rigidbody2D.AddForce(vector2.UP*jumpforce); this should work smoothly